# Modernizr don't add prefixes to my CSS Gradients

Tags: css, modernizr, linear-gradients

I'm trying to use Modernizr with css gradients.
I've read that Modernizr is now capable to add prefixes. 
So, I have set this in my css file:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #AAA);
```

And if I understand this should be transformed to:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #AAA);
```

But nothing happens and my gradient is not displayed. Is that a bug or am I missing something ?

Comment: where did you hear that modernizr can add vendor prefixes? AFAIK it doesn't

Comment: try [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) from lea verou if you want vendor prefixes, although there are loads of these tools out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modernizr does not add vendor prefixes. It only checks what a browser supports.

You can use this jQuery plugin.
https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Css3-Finalize it will automatically add vendor prefixes. But it has limited supported for linear-gradient.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this library but as you say, it doesn't seem to work with linear-gradient.

Comment: It do only support in this format, eg linear-gradient(#ffffff, #e5e5e5). It must be hexadecimal and have 6 signs (cant be 3).

Comment: Here is a list of what it supports https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Css3-Finalize/wiki/Rules-supported

Comment: Well, work great this way... I was using sass with mixins to prefixe my css rules but this seem to be a great alternative.

Comment: I've find this library from Lea Verou which work better: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree

Answer (score 3):

Modernizr is a JavaScript library.  It will not change the behavior of your CSS.  The prefix stuff in Modernizr generates the correctly prefixed CSS property name if it is needed for the browser on which it is running.  Your sample code has no JavaScript; it is just CSS;  Modernizr won't change its behavior.

Comment: I totally misunderstood what is modernizr... Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is http://prefixr.com/index.php